# Xamarin : Out of memory issue

Tags: android, memory, crash, xamarin

I have created a UI that is rich with PNG images for a Xamarin Android application, mostly images are assigned declaratively in the AXML layouts and range from 5 KB to 100 KB in size, unfortunately after running the application and navigating between Activities for sometime the application crashes with messages in the LogCat mentioning memory issues as follow

02-14 21:01:34.856: E/dalvikvm-heap(18277): Out of memory on a 4320016-byte allocation.

02-14 21:01:34.876: D/skia(18277): --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap

Also when I monitored the application using Xamarin Profiler, I found that the memory allocation chart goes up on launching an activity but doesn't go down on closing the activity (although I am using Finish method to close it), which means that the memory consumed by the activity does not get deallocated!

Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: The file size is irrelevant.  I can make a 10K file which needs more RAM than a 1MB file. What size are the bitmaps?  Are you recycling the bitmaps in onStop()?

Comment: I assume by the size of the Bitmap you mean size of the ImageView or the View using the images, I am using many images as backgrounds, so that's all the screen size, some backgrounds directly uses PNG files and others use xml files to tile a PNG image. The images are assigned to Views declaratively so I am not sure how to recycle them.

Comment: Displaying efficiently http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html make sure your bitmaps are eligible for collection. You could take it a step further with weak references. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519203/xamarin-out-of-memory-issue

Answer (score 1):

We had exact same issue, and we had to remove background image to resolve it. I am not sure why Xamarin hasn't received bug report for this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34474379/shouldn%C2%B4t-gc-run-automatically-in-xamarin-android-before-runing-out-of-memory) recently and I solved it by calling `GC.Collect()` whenever the problematic activity gets closed

Answer (score -1):

Add below line in your manifest file,

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

Comment: That would only hide the problem for a while